# Profile single function in gprof

Tags: c++, gprof

Is it possible to use gprof to line-profile a single function in C++?

Something like:

```
gprof -l -F function_name ...
```

, which does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done easily with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). It is a wonderful tool if you have the chance to use it in your development environment. It even have and graphical interface [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try using options with **[symspec]** to filter the results.  gprof 2.18.0 says that **-F** and **-f** are deprecated and to use symspec instead.

Also, **-l** may not work with binaries compiled with newer versions of gcc.  Try **gcov** instead.

Comment: I am using icc (icpc) i.e intel compiler on Linux and cannot get gcov working on it! I shall check out symspec. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a suspected performance problem? If you have a preconception of where it is, chances are it's not there. If you really want to find performance problems, first you may need to look beyond some [myths perpetuated by **gprof**](http://archive.today/9r927).

Comment: dead link; can't find this topic through google either

Comment: @Nate: I just updated the link. Some "wise persons" thought it was "not constructive".